# Elementary OS Freya. HDMI sound is not changing automatically

Tags: release-freya, sound, hdmi

I am aware that this is an usual Linux issue so that OS doesn't change sound to HDMI output automatically when HDMI screen is available.

However Elementary OS team managed to make HDMI screen to work much better than ANY other unix distribution (even on Ubuntu it doesn't work properly) so maybe it would be possible to have the same awesome functionality for sound as well ?

Comment: This should be posted as a feature request here: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+addspec